# Swift NumberFormatter appends Unicode spaces to currency strings even when the currency symbol is blank

Tags: ios, swift, currency, numberformatter

In iOS 13 it appears that in certain Locales, `NumberFormatter` appends a Unicode NO-BREAK SPACE or NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE to a string representation of the number, even when `NumberFormatter's` `currencySymbol` property is set to "" (blank).

Here's an example of this:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "uk_US (current)")
let numberString = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 1))!
print ("-->\(numberString)<--")
```

Does anyone know a way of suppressing that appended space, short of having to filter it out of every converted string in other code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your own positive and negative formats to avoid such cases. Note that you should always set the locale before setting the formats and there is no need to initialize a `NSNumber` object from your value, you can use `Formatter`'s `string(for:)` method:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "uk_US")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = "##0.00"
numberFormatter.negativeFormat = "-##0.00"
let value: Double = 1
let numberString = numberFormatter.string(for: value) ?? ""   // "1,00"
print ("-->\(numberString)<--") // "-->1,00<--\n"
```

---

For locales where there might not have fraction digits:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
// numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
let digits = numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits
let zeros = digits == 0 ? "" : "." + String(repeating: "0", count: digits)
numberFormatter.positiveFormat = "##0" + zeros
numberFormatter.negativeFormat = "-##0" + zeros
let value: Double = 1
let numberString = numberFormatter.string(for: value) ?? ""   // "1"
print ("-->\(numberString)<--") // "-->1<--\n"
```

Comment: This works (interesting!) but it isn't generic to all currencies.  For example, Locale(identifier: "ja_JP") formats Japanese Yen, which doesn't use decimals points.  If I define positiveFormat and negativeFormat as you've shown, I would need to modify them based on the local currency, which negates some of the benefit of using NumberFormatter.

Comment: I thought you were trying to use a fixed locale. Check my last edit

Comment: I like it!  But the more I think about it, I'm sure this is just an iOS 13 bug.  I worked around it by removing all UNICODE non-breaking spaces but ... why would anyone ever want a non-breaking space at the end of a string, Apple?  ;-)